# Formula to convert time to pixels

Tags: functions

I have a list of times represented as `000000` to `240000`.  For a web application, I convert those times to pixels by simply dividing by 100, so that their display position is ordered from the top of the page.  In other words, the time `160000` becomes `1600px`.  This works fine for times which are "on the hour", but obviously, there is a problem when the time is more complex.  For example, `163000` becomes `1630px` when, in order to display proportionally, it should be `1650px`.  How can I achieve this mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a "time" of the form: `t = HHMMSS`, we want to convert it to a four digit number of pixels representing $100$ times the number of hours that have elapsed since midnight. Using Python $3.3$ together with the flooring and modulo operations, we can achieve this goal by doing something like this:

```
def time2pixels(t):
    seconds = t % 100            # Get the last two digits.

    minutes = int(t / 100) % 100 # Get the middle two digits.
    minutes += seconds / 60.0    # Convert the seconds to minutes and add it on.

    hours = int(t / 10000)       # Get the first two digits.
    hours += minutes / 60.0      # Convert the minutes to hours and add it on.

    return int(hours * 100)      # Convert from hours to pixels.

print(time2pixels(163000))       # Outputs: 1650
```

Comment: Love it, thanks.